# Complete object and initialization, using delegating constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have one misunderstanding about delegating constructor. A delegating constructor is defined as follows (12.6.2/6 N3797):

> A mem-initializer-list can delegate to another constructor of the
>   constructor’s class using any class-ordecltype that denotes the
>   constructor’s class itself.

and 12.6.2/8:

> **After the call to a constructor for class X has completed**, if a member
>   of X is neither initialized nor given a value during execution of the
>   compound-statement of the body of the constructor, the member has
>   indeterminate value.

That is, X is complete after the execution of one's constructor body is complete. In the case of delegating constructor, like the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct A
{
    A(int)    
    {
        cout << "A(int)" << endl;
    }

    A() : A(4)
    {
        cout << "A()" << endl;
    }
};

A a;

int main()
{

}
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ab301ad6b61af9d)

In the case whether object a is completed `A(int)` body has completed or it is completed after `A()` body has completed?

Comment: Why does it matter? Can you show an example whose behavior pivots on the answer to this question?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I can't. What is purpose of the rule?

Comment: 12.6.2/8 applies to a non-delegating constructor only - it starts with "In a non-delegating constructor...". In your example, it applies to `A(int)` but not to `A()`. Though again, I don't quite see what difference it makes.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You mean in a delegating constructor actual initialization is performed by target constructor. Delegating constructor acts as just member function, doesn't it?

Comment: By the ultimate non-delegating constructor in the (possibly long) chain of constructors delegating to each other, to be precise.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It seems to be true. Thank you.